# Can I link my account to one that I deleted?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts, merge-accounts

Say that I open two accounts by mistake on the same SE site. There's a procedure in place for linking them.

Is there a similar procedure in place if I accidentally deleted my account? Can I dig up the user number of the anonymized account and link it to my current one?

Comment: Just for clarity's sake, is "deleted" what you really mean? It's very hard to accidentally [delete an account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account?rq=1), if you've cast votes or made more than one post, you have to go through a process of contacting SE to do it, it's more than just accidentally pressing the wrong button.

Comment: @JasonC Perhaps accidentally isn't the right word to use. At the time i meant to do it, but I sort of regret it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, once deleted the account is lost for good and can't be viewed by anyone, not even high rep users. Moderators do see some stats for deleted accounts, but also not the full profile.

Account deletion is one of the few actions on Stack Exchange which can't be undone.

Simply pay extra attention and do not delete your accounts "by mistake".